# Shellscript works from command line but not with cron

Tags: linux, mysql, cron

I'm setting up a standby or fail over server for our website. Part of this is to a nightly dump of the database from the production server, ftp it to the standby server. Once on the standby server I purge the copy database then import the fresh data dump. I do this between 2:00am and 2:25am, so essentially the two databases are in sync. (There is a github reason for doing all this but I won't go into the details since it has no bearing on my problem.) I have a very simple script to do this:

```
############################
# clear data first - truncate all tables in mydatabase_db1 

echo "purging current standby database"

mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -Nse 'show tables' mydatabase_db1 | while read table; do mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e "drop table $table" mydomains_db1; done 

echo 'Data purged from current database'>>/var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/import.log

#import data

echo "Importing production data dump"
mysql -uUSER -ppPASSWORD mydatabase_db1 < pe_data_dump.sql

echo 'Data imported into standby database' >>/var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/import.log
# remove todays data dump (not really, I'm still testing)

# rm /var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/pe_data_dump.sql >> /var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com import.log 2>&1

echo 'Data dump file removed'>>/var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/import.log

###########################
```

I can run this script from the shell with no problem. I cannot however get cron to successfully run it. This cron job was set up by root and run by root.

```
25      2      *       *       *       /var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/importData.sh
```

The data dump is delivered successfully from the production server:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 admin_ftp psacln 621487802 Jun 26 02:00 pe_data_dump.
```

I don't get why cron won't run this.

Comment: I'm assuming you just posted real credentials (username / password) here, so please change them on your server immediately.

Comment: Have you made sure your file is executable? (`chmod +x /var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/importData.sh`)

Comment: No, those are not real user name and password.

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't including the full path to the dump file..

Comment: I was assuming because you replaced them with `ADMIN` and `PASSWORD` in one place but not the other. Please answer your own question below, by including the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, figured it out.

mysql -uUSER -ppPASSWORD mydatabase_db1 < pe_data_dump.sql

I needed to add the full path to the dumpfile name, i.e. /var/www/vhosts/standby.piccexcellence.com/pe_data_dump.sql

cron liked that....